# Android TitleBar is still showing in design view even though I removed it in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am using activity and so I have to create my own toolbar and add it. Only problem is, the current default titlebar is not being removed even though I modified my styles.xml accordingly.

This is my file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

I have clearly stated "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

I even tried this in one of my activity classes:

```
public class ViewCars extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.carspage);
        }
}
```

And it crashes!

This is the actual error from the Android Studio:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{benj.samplesapp/benj.samplesapp.ViewCars}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

My android manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

How do I remove the old one?

Comment: Is this in an emulator, or on a device?

Comment: Well, I am trying to run it on the emulator but it keeps crashing

Comment: The device is a S3 on the emulator

Comment: Sorry, I meant layout designer, not emulator. Anyway, please post your stack trace.

Comment: I have updated my question, please see the trace there

Comment: Yep, that's still got an `ActionBar`. Are you sure you're setting the correct theme in your manifest?

Comment: I think I do, but I can't seem to change that one to the NoTheme one. Please look at my updated question

Comment: You've got the `<application>` theme set as `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Change it to `AppTheme`.

Comment: Change it to just "AppTheme"? So android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Yep, that's it.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Hi, it works mate :). Only problem is, the recyclerview is overlapping it now - is there a way to fix the toolbar to the top so that nothing overlaps it?

Comment: That's determined by your layout XML. It depends on what type of `ViewGroup` those `View`s are in.

Comment: Did you try using <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> </style> under your theme in styles.xml?

Comment: Thanks guys it works now :) +1 to all - especially Mike M. for helping me out promptly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you defined a style with no action bar but never applied it to your activity actually in your manifest file you are applying `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light`to your whole application and that is why your activity gets an action bar. so in your manifest file change your activity declaration to

```
    <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:theme:"@style/AppTheme" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

and remove `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`from your ViewCars class

Comment: Thanks, I tried the other solutions provided in the comments above and they all work - and I have given credit to all, including yourself. I just want this answer, as this too may certainly benefit others